# How to solve Windows mouse lag issues?

Tags: windows, windows-10, mouse, lag

My USB mouse (nothing fancy): Connect IT CI-390.

It happens in Windows 10 x64, usually once or twice per half an hour. It is really annoying when Windows decides to stop my mouse for half a second. I am mostly using Linux without any issues - this mouse lags have not occurred once under Linux (Kubuntu 16.04). I am using Windows only for gaming, so I was really surprised that Windows fail even in that task - I always thought that HW compatibility is under Windows (current/supported version) great.

**Any ideas on what could be causing this and how to fix it?**

Turning off antivirus (Avast) and firewall (Comodo) doesn't help. OS is fully updated. Also note that whole PC doesn't lag (freeze), only mouse - e.g. the game is still running, I am able to move my character via keyboard. It happens even when not in-game, just using browser. One time it happened when I didn't have opened any application, just for half a second mouse was frozen and I could not move the cursor on desktop.

I suspect Windows are doing something wrong with USB, because it seems that a set of wireless game-pads (which works flawlessly when connected to other PC) is being every ~20 minutes disconnected and reconnected (USB beep sound and momentarily non-responsive controls). But I have no idea how to troubleshoot this USB failures.

---

Edit1: Tried different ports, reinstalled mouse drivers (well, I doubt they are really different since they are the generic ones for HID devices). For the record the mouse is "WARLORD MOUSE for gamers; connect IT CI-390". I doubt the mouse is responsible, because this mouse freeze literally NEVER happened under Linux (I am using it several times more than Windows) and in previous Windows 10 installation it was also working fine.

Bought new mouse and this time Windows are not broken and mouse is working as well as in Linux. It is sad that I had to buy a new mouse, because *gaming* OS had broken support and (by many ppl) non-desktop OS was running it always without a hitch...

Comment: Have you tried with a different mouse on windows machine to check behaviour?

Comment: @RiteshKumarJalan I haven't, didn't thought it could be a hw issue when the mouse is working in Linux flawlessly. I'll try some older mouse later and post results.

Comment: Different mouse (different manufacturer) exhibits same problem (in this case shortly after logging in there were several of those lags).

Comment: Mouse lag in Windows 10 can also be related to LAN connectivity issues. Disabling the LAN adapter to see if the lagging stops is a tip I've heard several times before. In fact, I have OpenVPN configured to connect to a network without public Internet access, and as soon as it's connected, my mouse starts lagging horribly. As soon as I close the VPN connection, it's fine again. It's not a permanent fix, obviously, but you might want to try disabling your LAN adapter for a while to see if it's related to that.

Comment: @DanielSaner That's weird, I'll give it a shot. But even if it helps it is kinda useless - what is a point of having a gaming mouse without access to the internet (I mostly play multiplayer games, no other NIC is enabled)? Also if the LAN driver/hw would be the culprit wouldn't my new mouse also exhibit same behavior? (It's running flawlessly.)

Comment: @monnef That's a good point, maybe your cause is a different one. If it was something causing a bus issue in general, it should also affect the new mouse (assuming both are on USB). And yes, the network thing is definitely not a workaround, just something to try and narrow down possible causes.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried a different mouse or a different computer or USB port?
And I feel stupid saying this... Have you tried turning it off and on again?

Comment: I have tried a different port (no luck there), but not a different mouse - I thought since it's working under Linux the HW should be fine, but I'll try older mouse. Off/On sadly is not working, this is a long lasting issue - it behaves like this for a two months I think.

Comment: Did the problem start around when you installed Linux? If so you many of somehow corrupted the mouse drivers. Try reinstalling the mouse drivers.

Comment: Different mouse (different manufacturer) exhibits same problem (in this case shortly after logging in there were several of those lags). I have installed Windows and Linux at a same time, so I can't really tell if it started with Linux. I'll try reinstalling mouse drivers.

Comment: I hope it works for you.

Comment: Sadly it didn't help. I had to "fix" this Windows bug by buying a new mouse :/.

Comment: I apologize that I could not help. The laser used in some gameing mice are very high quality, but don't last long. I had a problem using an Razer Naga with a Mac. It worked fine until about a year later. It was the laser. Needless to say, I got a new mouse.

Comment: No need to apologize ;). I appreciate your time and also your answer may help others (that's why I upvoted it :) ). I am sure it's something with Windows, because as I said many times, it still works fine under Linux. Maybe driver of something else was interfering, but I have no clue how to troubleshoot that sort of thing.

Comment: If you have access to a viny cutter you could use it put the Linux logo on the mouse. T

Answer (score 1):

You can try to remove the driver in the "Device Manager", unplug, plug again and wait for the driver installation by Windows.

The problem may come from a corrupt file.

Comment: Tried that, no change.